# Yii 2.0 showing Warning: Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: yii

I am new to yii 2.0. I installed my first Yii2.o application on my server and configred URL to use user friendly urls. However, I am getting

Warning: Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

message when I go to the web/about/ URL. I tried to remove the base rout using "defaultRoute" in web.php but that is also not possible. 
Please help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with Yii 2.0. It's a PHP misconfiguration.
Probably, you've enabled mysql extension twice. Search in your php.ini and extensions ini files:

`extension=mysql.so`
or
`extension=mysql.dll`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fix it by deleting this line in my php.ini:

```
extension=mysql.so
```

located in: /etc/php5/apache2/ and restarting apache2 service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```